# How do I prevent a keyup event from bubbling into a MUI Snackbar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We have created a notification system that uses the material ui Snackbar with an action button and close button. I've added a listener event for `enter` so that specific notification's action will fire and close the Snackbar. The issue I have is that after this action has been performed, the default behavior of chrome still has the button that triggers the notification focused. If enter is pressed, it not only triggers the notification but also the action button in the notification. Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import { NotifierConfirm, enqueueInfo } from '@paragon/notification-tools';
import { deleteDocument } from '../../actions/documents';
import { getSelectedDocument } from '../../selectors/documents';
import { jobIsLocked } from '../../modules/jobLocking'; // eslint-disable-line

const styles = ({
  border: {
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

class DeleteDocument extends React.Component {
  state = {
    deleteDocumentOpen: false,
  }

  onDeleteFile = () => {
    if (jobIsLocked()) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: true });
  }

  closeDeleteDocument = () => {
    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: false });
  };

  onConfirmDelete = () => {
    this.props.onDeleteFile(this.props.selectedDocument.id);
    this.setState({ deleteDocumentOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Tooltip disableFocusListener id="delete-tooltip" title="Delete Document">
          <div>
            <IconButton
              className={`${classes.border} deleteDocumentButton`}
              disabled={(this.props.selectedDocument == null)}
              onClick={this.onDeleteFile}
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
        <NotifierConfirm
          open={this.state.deleteDocumentOpen}
          onClose={this.closeDeleteDocument}
          onClick={this.onConfirmDelete}
          message="Are you sure you want to DELETE this document?"
          buttonText="Delete"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selectedDocument = getSelectedDocument(state);

  return {
    selectedDocument,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onDeleteFile: (documentId) => {
      dispatch(deleteDocument(documentId));
    },
    enqueueInfo,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(DeleteDocument));
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles, WithStyles, StyleRulesCallback } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import RootRef from '@material-ui/core/RootRef';

interface NotifierConfirmProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: any;
  onClick: () => void;
  message: string;
  messageSecondary?: any;
  buttonText: string;
}

type OwnProps = NotifierConfirmProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>;

const styles: StyleRulesCallback = () => ({
  snackbar: {
    marginTop: 85,
    zIndex: 10000000,
    '& div:first-child': {
      '& div:first-child': {
        width: '100%',
      },
    },
  },
  close: {
    padding: 8,
    marginLeft: 8,
  },
  buttonColor: {
    backgroundColor: '#F3D06E',
  },
  messageDiv: {
    width: '100%',
  }
});

class NotifierConfirmComponent extends React.Component<OwnProps> {
  notifierRef: React.RefObject<{}>;
  constructor(props: OwnProps) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.notifierRef = React.createRef();
    this.focusNotifier = this.focusNotifier.bind(this);
  }
  keyPressHandler = (event: any) => {
    if (!this.props.open) return;
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.props.onClose();
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.props.onClick();
    }
  }

  focusNotifier() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    // this.notifierRef.current.focus();  this will not work
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyPressHandler, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.keyPressHandler, false);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RootRef rootRef={this.notifierRef}>
          <Snackbar
            className={classes.snackbar}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'center',
            }}
            open={this.props.open}
            onClose={this.props.onClose}
            ContentProps={{
              'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
            }}
            message={
              <div className={classes.messageDiv} id="message-id">
                {this.props.message}<br />
                {this.props.messageSecondary}
              </div>}
            action={[
              <Button
                className={`${classes.buttonColor} confirmActionButton`}
                variant="contained"
                key={this.props.buttonText}
                size="small"
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
              >
                {this.props.buttonText}
              </Button>,
              <IconButton
                key="close"
                aria-label="Close"
                color="inherit"
                className={classes.close}
                onClick={this.props.onClose}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>,
            ]}
          />
        </RootRef>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export const NotifierConfirm = withStyles(styles)(NotifierConfirmComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your callback you should call `Event.preventDefault()` or `Event.stopPropagation()`, it's worth notice that this two aren't the same. Here the docs: [Prevent Default](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), [Stop Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: This works for the initial keypress, but I do actually want the `enter` key to "click" the action button once the notification is open. It either bubbles all the way up or stops when it opens the notification.